# Only subset of Push Notifications received when watching for changes on user's entire Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

Our app would like to receive notifications when changes have been made to anything on a user's drive.  We are using the `watch` endpoint to do this, authorized with the broadest `drive` scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/watch

However, only changes with a `X-Goog-Resource-State` of 'change` seem to be ever delivered.  There are no notifications when adding or removing files.  This seems erroneous, as when I query https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes, those add/remove changes are indeed in the returned list.

Comment: After adding or removing files in Drive, you are not getting the push notifications ? only if you modify (update) a file?

Comment: Correct. No add/remove notifications.

Comment: If you use a different environment like: https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/,  are you able to get those notifications?

Comment: No, it has the same behavior.  The change IDs seem to be out of sync, as well.  Most notifications I receive return 404s when I try to get them. But the 'delete' and 'add' notifications for the actual files are never sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to Drive API v3, which seems to have resolved the problem.  I am receiving add/remove notifications now.